# How write integration tests for Angular.js application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, integration-testing

Our team is working on single page application based on `AngularJS`. Our team has around twenty UI developers. Also, we have QA team which is testing UI part of the application using Selenium. We already have unit-tests (coverage approximately 40%). But we have a lot of regression in last time. We are trying to understand how we can improve our testing approach.

According to [this article](http://qa-matters.com/2014/12/28/layers-of-test-automation/) (and this image: [Three levels of tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yOBU.png)). There is an additional level in our application which it is not covered yet: *Integration tests*. But I can't find any good article which will have answer to such questions:

- How to understand which units should be covered by integration tests?
- How to understand how much integration tests we need to write?
- How share responsibility between integration testing by UI team with UI testing by QA team?

Comment: I think that there are no single answer for your question. There are multiple choices how to write tests and how to organize the process of testing. Personally i can recommend an excellent "BDD in action" book that covers this themes.

Comment: A very good article for Angular Js integration testing http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/angular-integration-tests . Hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: @AndreiBelokopytov I understand that no silver bullet for this subject. Thank you for the book!!! I am a beginner in writing tests, so I am looking literature about it.

Comment: @Vikash thank you for the article!

Comment: IMO integration tests are validating the primary business logic needs. "The user can log in and view a profile." "When I hit the load balancer from an external machine the cache hits." they are nice to run periodically on CI